# Jmeter Facebook Issue

Tags: testing, jmeter

- I am testing the mobile application with a **HTTP(s) script recorder**(mobile is connected to **JMeter** via computer IP address.).
- From an app, if I try to login with facebook then it shows **failure report** in **jmter**,b ut if I hit the stop button from JMeter(https script recorder) and then after if I try to login with facebook then I can easily able login with facebook.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to record HTTPS calls you need to install JMeter's self-signed certificate onto your device.

1. Start [JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. Locate `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` file under "bin" folder of your JMeter installation and transfer it somehow to your device (i.e. send it to yourself by email)
3. Open the certificate on your mobile device and follow your operating system certificate installation dialog to set this up

Now you should be able to record HTTPS traffic. Note that certain mobile operating systems don't support HTTPS proxy on Wi-Fi connection settings level so you may have to use a 3rd-party application for this (i.e. [ProxyDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid&hl=en_GB) for Android)

You can also try out a [cloud-based proxy service for recording JMeter tests](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420545-BlazeMeter-Proxy-Recorder-Mobile-and-web-#mobile) which automates certificate installation process and is capable of exporting the recorded script in "SmartJMX" mode with automatic correlation applied.

Comment: Thanks for the answer  @Dmitri, but don't know why I am not able to login with facebook if I am using my PC IP address on my mobile as proxy server,Once again thank you very much.